# Get variable from link in PHP, issue

Tags: php

I have URL below:

```
session.php?action=create_program
```

Then I have the following piece of code:

```
if( isset($_GET['action']) ){ $action= $_GET['action']; $action=''; }
```

It returns an empty string while it should return ''create_program'

Comment: ... you set it to an empty string with `$action='';`....

Comment: I check the condition, if the $_GET is not set then I set it to empty, otherwise it should be equal to the $_get

Comment: looks like you want `else` with `$action='';`

Comment: @DaniM Well, that's not the code you've written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you were trying to set it to empty if you didn't receive anything in your get request. So either do it like this

```
if( isset($_GET['action']) ){
    $action= $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $action='';
}
```

Or, even simpler, give a default value that remains set if the get parameter is absent.

```
$action = '';
if( isset($_GET['action']) ){
    $action= $_GET['action'];
}
```

Finally, as suggested by Cashbee in the comment below, you can use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check whether `$_GET['action']` was set and, in case it's not, give a default value to `$action`.

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
```

Comment: You could even shorten that with ternary operator: `$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';`

Answer (score 2):

Easy is the use of the ternary operator like this:

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
```

You should always check if the variable is set or empty.

```
$action = empty($_GET['action']) ? '' : $_GET['action'];
```

Or even better, use the PHP filter functions.

```
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
```

This has the advantage, you can even use rules, to give the appropriate result, like described in http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `$action` to empty at last that's why it is returning an empty string

```
if( isset($_GET['action']) )
{
  $action= $_GET['action'];
// $action='';  //Just remove this code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//$action will be empty if not have $_GET['action'];, just for PHP7
$action = $_GET['action'] ?? '';
```

hope can help you!

Comment: Thank you, but when I echo the $action, then I get 1

Comment: Did you mean `??`? Or perhaps `?:`?